# Table missing line multicolumn

Tags: tables

Cant make it happen guys, the missing line is killing me, any help?

```
\begin{table}[!htpb] \label{tabela1}
    \centering
    \begin{small} 
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} 

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Constante de Velocidade}\\ \cline{2-3} 

            \raisebox{1.5ex}{Função de Ativação} & Valores Iniciais de $k_1$ & Valores Retornados de $k_1$ &    \raisebox{1.5ex}{Energia de Rede}  \\ \hline

            \multirow{3}{4em}{Tangente Hiperbólica} & X & X & X  \\ 
             & 5& X & X  \\ 
             & 6& X & X  \\ \hline
            \multirow{3}{4em}{Sigmóide} & X & X & X  \\ 
            & 5& X & X  \\ 
            & 6& X & X  \\ \hline

        \end{tabular} 
    \end{small}
    \caption{Testes das funções de Ativação da Rede}
    \label{t_cronograma}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have complete code to start from.

Comment: Could you also describe what output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the below tag helps your need:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htpb] \label{tabela1}
\centering
\begin{small} 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Constante de Velocidade} &\\ \cline{2-3} 
        \raisebox{1.5ex}{Função de Ativação} & Valores Iniciais de $k_1$ 
        & Valores Retornados de $k_1$ &     \raisebox{1.5ex}{Energia de Rede}
        \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{4em}{Tangente Hiperbólica} & X & X & X  \\ 
         & 5& X & X  \\ 
         & 6& X & X  \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{4em}{Sigmóide} & X & X & X  \\ 
        & 5& X & X  \\ 
        & 6& X & X  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\end{small}
\caption{Testes das funções de Ativação da Rede}
\label{t_cronograma}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `small` is not an environment but switch to small font size.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

With fully exploit of recent version of `multirow` package and correct use of command `\small`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5em}|c|c|>{\Centering}p{5em}|}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\centering
                Função de Ativação}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Constante de Velocidade}    
                    &   \multirow{2}{=}{\centering
                                        Energia de Rede}    \\ 
    \cline{2-3}
    &   Valores Iniciais de $k_1$
        &   Valores Retornados de $k_1$     &               \\ 
    \hline
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering
                Tangente Hiperbólica} 
    &   X   &   X   &   X                                   \\
    &   5   &   X   &   X                                   \\
    &   6   &   X   &   X                                   \\ 
    \hline
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering
                Sigmóide} 
    &   X   &   X   &   X                                   \\
    &   5   &   X   &   X                                   \\
    &   6   &   X   &   X                                   \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Testes das funções de Ativação da Rede}
\label{tabela1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

You can remove package `ragged2e` but in this case the columns headers had to be defined as:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{5em}|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5em}|}
```

Alternative solution with use of `booktabs` for more "professional" (as stated in package documentation) looks:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{p{5em} c c >{\Centering}p{5em} }
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{=}{\centering
                Função de Ativação}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Constante de Velocidade $k_1$}    
                    &   \multirow{2}{=}{\centering
                                        Energia de Rede}    \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    &   Valores Iniciais
        &   Valores Retornados  &                           \\ 
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering
                Tangente Hiperbólica} 
    &   X   &   X   &   X                                   \\
    &   5   &   X   &   X                                   \\
    &   6   &   X   &   X                                   \\ 
    \addlinespace
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering
                Sigmóide} 
    &   X   &   X   &   X                                   \\
    &   5   &   X   &   X                                   \\
    &   6   &   X   &   X                                   \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Testes das funções de Ativação da Rede}
\label{tabela1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```